# Worked from France for the last 6 months for US clients without paying French taxes. What should I do now?

Tags: france, taxes, us-citizens, freelance

I need some advice, or a good recommendation for a tax expert.

I've been living on with my PACSée in France on a carte de séjour vie privée/familiale for the last 6 months and have continued my full-time freelance work with my US clients. When I got the carte de séjour, I specifically asked about my situation at the préfecture, and I was given the impression that I could continue working without any problem. After doing more research, it looks like this was wrong.

So here's the rub: following the supposedly bad information I got, I never set up a business structure for my professional activities here in France and I've continued paying my quarterly taxes in the US. I'm happy to set up a business here (I earn more than the limit for auto-entrepeneur), but I'm worried about the fact that I'm 6 months late, and possibly needing to repay taxes and social contributions for the last 6 months, or even getting in hotter water because I unknowingly broke the rules. Additionally, my PACSée needs to report my income on her taxes.

I'm really not sure what to do, so any advice, or suggestions for a consultant or tax expert that is familiar with expat freelancers in the Paris/Yvelines region would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've been in the same boat recently.  Working in France is not like working in the US unfortunately--you can't just hang a shingle on your door and declare yourself in business. At least you're on a vie privée/familiale so you can basically do whatever you want.  I don't know if we're allowed to make suggestions for specific people on here, but I found a tax expert who helped me sort it all out. You might need to pay some back taxes but it probably won't be a disaster--especially if you write letters explaining your situation in good faith, they do seem to honor that.